# Is mixed inherited by the children of the element of an xsd schema?

Tags: inheritance, xsd, complextype, mixed

A mixed complex type element can have text as well between its children.
Does the children inherit this mixed feature as well? In other words, if the children are not of a mixed type, 
can they have text between their children as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `mixed` is not inherited by children elements.

**Given this XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="grandchild" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**This XML document instance:**

```
<root>
  text1
  <child>
    text2
    <grandchild/>
  </child>
</root>
```

**Would be invalid** because the `mixed` content model of `root` is not passed along to the content model of `child`.

**A validating parser would issue an error such as the following:**

> Element 'child' cannot have character [children], because the type's
>   content type is element-only.

See also the similar but different question [Is mixed inherited when a complexType is extended?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8736931/290085)